# Must I only read serialized data using unserialize? Is there an easier way?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm new to PHP. I'm using a WooCommerce 3rd party plugin that stores the product extra data in one row called `product_extras` under `woocommerce_order_itemmeta` table and the value is a serialized data as below.

```
a:4:{s:10:"product_id";i:5353;s:5:"title";s:36:"Product Test";s:6:"groups";a:1:{i:8416;a:1:{i:8417;a:8:{s:4:"type";s:6:"select";s:5:"label";s:0:"";s:2:"id";s:20:"pewc_group_8416_8417";s:8:"group_id";s:4:"8416";s:8:"field_id";i:8417;s:5:"price";d:0;s:5:"value";s:8:"Extra";s:9:"flat_rate";a:0:{}}}}s:17:"price_with_extras";d:0;}
```

So, is there a way to read the data above directly?

Comment: Well it is a string, so you can so whatever you want with it directly in that respect. You could also write your own way of parsing / using that data if you _really_ wanted to, but I don't see what's wrong with using `unserialize`. I'm also unsure about what is hard about one function call.

Comment: What is the problem you're having? that string is the result of using `serialize()` so it makes sense that `unserialize()` would convert it back. it is a PHP specific format.